# SceneBuilder JavaFX Font size Scaling

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I can't seem to figure out how to scale the font to the size of the window. Using normal responsive CSS sizes like 3em doesn't work (it stays the same size).

I know how to make it work if there was no FXML involved, but I can't figure out how to interact with any CSS or FXML variables from Java.